# Webpack 2.3.3 - TypeError: $export is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, webpack-2, babel-loader

I have this Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './lib/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'suman.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['latest'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  node: {
    assert: 'empty',
    buffer: 'mock',
    child_process: 'empty',
    cluster: 'empty',
    console: 'mock',
    constants: 'empty',
    crypto: 'empty',
    dgram: 'empty',
    dns: 'mock',
    domain: 'empty',
    events: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    http: 'empty',
    https: 'empty',
    module: 'empty',
    net: 'mock',
    os: 'empty',
    path: 'empty',
    process: 'mock',
    punycode: 'mock',
    querystring: 'empty',
    readline: 'empty',
    repl: 'empty',
    stream: 'empty',
    string_decoder: 'empty',
    timers: 'empty',
    tls: 'mock',
    tty: 'mock',
    url: 'empty',
    util: 'empty',
    v8: 'mock',
    vm: 'empty',
    zlib: 'empty',
  }
};
```

I run $webpack at the command line and I get an outputted file, I load the file in the browser like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Suman tests</title>
  <script src="../../../dist/suman.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If I load this html file in the browser, I get:

```
suman.js:48039 Uncaught TypeError: $export is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (suman.js:48039)
    at __webpack_require__ (suman.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (suman.js:46862)
    at __webpack_require__ (suman.js:20)
    at Object.hasOwnProperty (suman.js:12300)
    at __webpack_require__ (suman.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (suman.js:10477)
    at __webpack_require__ (suman.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (suman.js:12321)
    at __webpack_require__ (suman.js:20)
```

I looked at a bunch of issues on Github and none of them seem to solve the problem. Anyone know what could be wrong?

I am on Webpack version 2.3.3.

on a side note - where can I find some polyfills for Node.js / NPM modules?

`$export` appears to be a function generated by Webpack, and here is some of it that appears in my output file:

```
var global = __webpack_require__(10),
    core = __webpack_require__(58),
    hide = __webpack_require__(33),
    redefine = __webpack_require__(34),
    ctx = __webpack_require__(59),
    PROTOTYPE = 'prototype';

var $export = function $export(type, name, source) {
  var IS_FORCED = type & $export.F,
      IS_GLOBAL = type & $export.G,
      IS_STATIC = type & $export.S,
      IS_PROTO = type & $export.P,
      IS_BIND = type & $export.B,
      target = IS_GLOBAL ? global : IS_STATIC ? global[name] || (global[name] = {}) : (global[name] || {})[PROTOTYPE],
      exports = IS_GLOBAL ? core : core[name] || (core[name] = {}),
      expProto = exports[PROTOTYPE] || (exports[PROTOTYPE] = {}),
      key,
      own,
      out,
      exp;
  if (IS_GLOBAL) source = name;
  for (key in source) {
```

Comment: What is `$export`? If that's what is failing, that is the place to start, and you haven't shown us the code for that.

Comment: You should also consider enabling sourcemaps with `devtool: "source-map"` so you get better stack traces.

Comment: @loganfsmyth $export function is not my code, it's the code generated by webpack, let me give you a link to it

Comment: @loganfsmyth I updated the question in response to your comment, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Along with

```
test: /\.js$/
```

you should have

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

as you can see in the usage examples: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage

e.g.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: ['latest'],
    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
  }
}
```

In this case, you are using `transform-runtime` which means Babel will insert references to `babel-runtime` into your code. The issue is that without `exclude: /node_modules/,`, or at least `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!babel-runtime)/,`, you are also telling `babel-runtime` to insert references to itself *inside* itself, which creates circular dependencies that will break the code.

Comment: hmmm, but I need node_modules, I have a ton of node.js code that I need to get into the browser....somehow.

Comment: Is there a way to get node_modules (like async module, bluebird, etc) into the browser while ignoring/excluding node_modules? I thought part of the purpose of Webpack was to bundle NPM modules for you....

Comment: I am happy to ignore node_modules, I just would like to know why that would fit my use case

Comment: The exclude in this case is specifically for `babel`, not for Webpack as a whole. I'll update the question.

Comment: oh, I see, huh, I guess webpack will still go through and source deps from node_modules, babel just won't transpile 'em...